# Removing Dynamically Created kmlLayer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that contains an embedded browser window.

I want to have my application create a kmlLayer.  I can do this on the fly with the following:

```
function addKmlLayer(kmlURL) {
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ url: kmlURL });
    kmlLayer.setMap(my_map);
}
```

I'm going to allow my users to add several kmlLayers.

I also know that I can remove the layer by using kmlLayer.setMap(null).

How do I find my previous kmlLayer to set it to null?  Is there a way to identify the kmlLayer (ID, Name, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to keep a global reference to the KmlLayer

```
var kmlLayer = null;
function addKmlLayer(kmlURL) {
    kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({ url: kmlURL });
    kmlLayer.setMap(my_map);
}
```

Then to hide it, this will work:

```
kmlLayer.setMap(null);
```

Might want to do:

```
if ((kmlLayer != null) && kmlLayer.setMap) kmlLayer.setMap(null);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm allowing users to select several kml files to display, and they don't have to be added at the same time.

Comment: So use an array for kmlLayer...  (and add that and the code that supports it to your question)